# ffmpeg command working in cmd but not in batch file

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch, watermark

I am having a command to convert mkv files in a folder to mp4. When I try to add watermark to the converted files, it works fine in cmd prompt but when I run it in batch file it gives me an error saying Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args. Following is the ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 20 -i %~d1%~p1%~n1.mkv -vf "drawtext=text='Watermark Text':x=10:y=H-th-10:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Calibri.ttf:fontsize=45:fontcolor=white@0.2: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 1000k %~d1%~p1%~n1
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use escape character for batch file:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 20 -i %~d1%~p1%~n1.mkv -vf ^"drawtext=text='Watermark Text':x=10:y=H-th-10:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Calibri.ttf:fontsize=45:fontcolor=white@0.2: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2^" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 1000k %~d1%~p1%~n1
```

Comment: Adding escape character didnt do the trick. In report im getting,

Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'text=Watermark Text:x=10:y=H-th-10:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/Calibri.ttf:fontsize=45:fontcolor=white@0.2: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2'
Error reinitializing filters!